# Apple's Magic mouse scroll button is not working on windows-7

Tags: mac, windows

After working on MAC OSX, i installed windows-7 32bit through boot camp. After installing, the magic mouse is connecting ok through Bluetooth. Its left and right buttons are working but scroll is not working.

What drivers or softwares i have to install to make the scroll work? Please inform me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you installed the Boot Camp drivers in Windows 7?  Available on your OS X install media.

Answer (score 1):

Following your initial installation of Windows 7 via Bootcamp you need to go a step further, boot into Windows and install the Bootcamp drivers supplied by Apple.  These can be found on your Mac's installation media or by searching for "Boot Camp Support Software" at [Apple's support downloads page](http://support.apple.com/downloads/#macoscomponents).  The installation of this software enables functions such as your Eject key, iSight camera, etc, as well as functionality for your Magic Mouse.

Hope that helps!